# Pass value from ActionFilterAttribute to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, actionfilterattribute

I have the following base controller with a string variable

```
public abstract class BaseController:Controller
{
    string encryptedSessionGuid;
}
```

All other controller derives from base controller and ActionMethod has a custom ActionFilterAttribute `CheckQueryString`-

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
    [CheckQueryString(new string[] {"sid"})]  
    public ActionResult SampleMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my custom attribute. It sends query string value to view. But I would like to send it base controller variable `encryptedSessionGuid` also.

```
public class CheckQueryString : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string[] keys;
    public CheckQueryString(string[] Keys) { keys = Keys; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            if (ctx.Request.QueryString[key] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(BulkSmsApplication.GlobalConfig.BaseUrl);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string value = ctx.Request.QueryString[key];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(BulkSmsApplication.GlobalConfig.BaseUrl);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
                    viewBag[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: As far as I see, passing `encryptedSessionGuid` to `SampleController` instance seems impossible due to `abstract` level & `private` scope in base class, including passing same field to `CheckQueryString` attribute. Can you explain further what you want to do with `encryptedSessionGuid`?